# Retrieving data from Database and binding to List<> using EntityFramework MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have a table student in my database with some values and i want to display those values in webgrid using entityframework.

I have done the samething before many times using Ado.net, but the purpose of this for me is just to learn entity framework and im absolute beginner to Entityframework.

I used database first approach for this and in created a model Student with Id,FirstName,LastName,City.

i also defined a List and i want to bind the result set from the database to this Student List and bind it to the webgrid

```
 public List<Student> stList;


    public  List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        stList = new List<Student>();
        EntityFWEntities OE = new EntityFWEntities();
        var Res = OE.Students;

    }
```

How can i assign the VAR value to List, also is this the correct approach i following or is there an other better approach, please correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the `List<Student>` just use `.ToList()` method.

```
public List<Student> stList;
public  List<Student> GetStudents()
{
    using (EntityFWEntities OE = new EntityFWEntities())
    {
        //Assuming student has 4 properties ID, Name, Roll, DOB
        stList = OE.Students.Select(s=> new MvcApplication4.Models.Student(){ ID=s.ID, Name=s.Name, Roll=s.Roll, DOB=s.DOB}).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it, it is giving error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication4.Student>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication4.Models.Student>'

Comment: Updated answer. Please check

Comment: thnku it worked fine, but is this the right way or is there any other better way than this?